# how can i include a variable at each array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have user model and i want the list of users as json and i want the `length of name` along with the response for each user but i do not how i can do this? I have tried as shown below and it resulted in `double render` error. If i take the respond_to from the loop then it returns nothing. so please help me.

```
@users = User.all
   @users.each do |user|
      length = user.name.count
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: @users.to_json(:include => [:length]) }
        end
      end
```

I want the response to be like

> [{"user":{"name":asgd,"id":1,"length":"4"}},{"user":{"name":asdfg,"id":2,"length":"5"}}]

Comment: Your desired response doesn't include any length.

Comment: How can i add methods along with as format.json { render json: all_users.to_json, :methods =>[:pic_url] } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@users = User.all
all_users = Array.new
@users.each do |user|
  all_users << {"id" => user.id, "name" => user.name,"length" => user.name.size}
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: all_users.to_json }
end
```

Comment: size didnt work. so i used count and there are sometimes no name then it displays undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `user.name.try(:length)` should guard you against no-names as well

Comment: How can i add methods along with as format.json { render json: all_users.to_json, :methods =>[:pic_url] } ?

Comment: but it adds "methods":["pic_url"] along with response and not the url

Comment: sorry and i have corrected and as you have told i used pic_url => user.pic_url instead of :methods =>[:pic_url]. Thank you any ways.